# Plotting Complex Quantity Functions

Tags: plotting, complex, faq

Trying to plot with complex quantities seems not to work properly in what I want to accomplish. I would like to know if there is a general rule/way of plotting when you have complex counterparts in your function. I tried looking up `ContourPlot` and `DensityPlot` but  I only have one single variable as `ContourPlot` asks for two variables in order to plot. The expression I am trying to plot is as so:

```
eqn := (25 Pi f I)/(1 + 10 Pi f I)
Plot[eqn,{f,-5,5}]
```

If there something else that is missing here?

Comment: `Plot` displays $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ functions. How is it supposed to interpret `I`?

Comment: Is your variable `f` supposed to be just real (as suggested by the domain in your `Plot` expression)? Or do you want it to take more general complex values, too?

Comment: @murray: Well the function  `f` is complex valued. It reads as `G(f) = (25 Pi f I) / (1 + 10 Pi f I)`. So, what I was trying to accomplish is plot the spectrum or "Fourier Transform (frequency response)", of the function $g(t)$. Where $f$ just represent the frequency variable from the time-domain. I hope that makes sense to clear up your question.

Comment: @night owl: a typical communication between a mathematician and a non-matthematician? (I think of a complex-valued function of a real variable; you speak about respone of frequency.) But I understand! You do have a function from the real numbers to the complex numbers, so the way to represent it visually is unclear. For things like density plots and contour plots, one is dealing with a domain consisting of pairs of reals or, equivalently,complex numbers and range real numbers. Your situation is precisely the reverse.

Comment: @murray: Edit: I meant to say the function `G` is complex, but can be seen from above.

Comment: @night owl: Stating "the function `G` is complex" is ambiguous. What is its domain? (just reals or all complex numbers?) Clearly its codomain is the complex numbers.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The way you could use `ContourPlot` here, assuming your variable `f` is complex (`f == x + I y`) :

```
eqn[x_, y_] := (25 Pi ( x + I y) I)/(1 + 10 Pi ( x + I y) I)

{ContourPlot[Re@eqn[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50], 
 ContourPlot[Im@eqn[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.5}, PlotPoints -> 50]}
```

[image]

These are respectively real and imaginary parts of the function `eqn`.

Let's plot the absolute value of `eqn` :

```
Plot3D[ Abs[ eqn[x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]

And we complement with the plot of real and imaginary parts of `eqn` in the real domain :

```
eqnR[x_] := (25 Pi x I)/(1 + 10 Pi x I)
Plot[{ Tooltip@Re@eqnR[x], Tooltip@Im@eqnR[x]}, {x, -0.25, 0.25}, 
      PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice To know how it would work to do it as a contour and how it looks. But I really just needed it to output a regular curve. I mentioned contour because I had looked up how to plot complex variables. I might have to accept the other answer as to that it what I was more so looking to get. It is to see what the frequency spectrum is of a function.

Comment: I added the real and imaginary parts of `eqn` in one plot. `Tooltips` help to distinguish parts of `eqn` while the mouse pointer is on a given curve.

Comment: You may have won back the title! This is what I got doing it in matlab, and gnu plot, but could not figure it out here. This is what the frequency response should resemble, from my results in the other programs. `:)`. Did you make this possible still using `Plot` by using the `Re@eqnR[x]` and `Im@eqnR[x]`.?

Comment: @nightowl I'am not sure what you are asking for. You can remove Tooltip as well if you want, here it is superfluous.

Comment: I understand what you were doing  with `Tooltip`. I was asking was using `{Re[], Im[]}` inside the `Plot` command gave the ability to view the real and imaginary components of the equation or if desired just one or the other. Because, when these are not used but instead `Plot[eqn,{f,xmin,xmax}]`, nothing is rendered in the output. And as a user, you wonder to yourself, what is this telling me because there was no errors, but nothing was plotted. So, I was just asking were `Re[]` and `Im[]` the key to get the results to display when plotting a complex quantity using the `Plot` command.

Comment: @nightowl I could agree there should be a message why it did not produce a reasonable plot, however you can expect there are two real components of the function `eqn` and M cannot decide what to do. This construct `{Re[], Im[]}` is a general approach to produce a few curves, you can add even more components therein, e.g.   `{Re[], Im[], Abs@eqn[]}`.

Comment: Yes, your are right. That would be a great feature if Mathematica can realize what you are trying to feed it to do and give slight suggestions as how you could adjust your input to get what you are looking for. Maybe in a `furture` version `:)`. But yes, that also works nicely, the `Abs[eqn]`. Though, `Abs@eqn[]` does not display the `Abs` of the function with the empty argument brackets `[]` placed  there, but when removed works perfectly as: `Abs@eqn`

Comment: Another question that comes to mind looking at one of the plots in comparison to the others. What information does the `ContourPlot` convey about your function? I guess what I am asking is, could it be some different domain where your function lies where it conveys certain vital information about the function you have, that could be helpful to you, depending on what type of analysis one is doing. If this makes sense?

Comment: I would advise only to study the issue on a case by case basis, otherwise there is no resonable answer.

Comment: Okay, Thank You.

Answer (score 35):

The following function gives the complete information for a function $f:\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$, by giving the absolute value as $z$-coordinate, and the argument as colour:

```
ComplexFnPlot[f_, range_, options___] := 
  Block[{rangerealvar, rangeimagvar, g}, 
    g[r_, i_] := (f /. range[[1]] :> r + I i);
    Plot3D[Abs@g[rangerealvar, rangeimagvar],
      {rangerealvar, Re@range[[2]], Re@range[[3]]},
      {rangeimagvar, Im@range[[2]], Im@range[[3]]}, options, 
      ColorFunction -> (Hue@Mod[Arg@g[#1, #2]/(2*Pi) + 1, 1] &), 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False]]
```

For example, the call

```
ComplexFnPlot[Gamma[z],{z,-3.5-3.5I,3.5+5.5I},PlotRange->{0,4}]
```

gives

[image: resulting graphics from the command above]

Positive real numbers are red, negative real numbers are cyan. One can e.g. see that the poles of the Gamma function are of order one because going round them you go through the colour cycle just once.

Comment: Yes, such a plot does encode "complete information". But discerning from such a plot just how the function behaves is problematic.

Comment: @murray: No more problematic than any other information gathered from graphs. Of course, reading from a graph can never replace a proper analysis. However it can give strong hints about what one is likely to find in that analysis.

Answer (score 14):

Here are two common ways to visualize complex functions.  The first plots the image of a rectangle in the complex plane.  The second plots real and imaginary contours on top of one another, illustrating the fact that they meet at right angles.

```
f[z_] := E^z;
pic1=ParametricPlot[{Re[f[x+I*y]],Im[f[x+I*y]]},
  {x,0,1},{y,0,Pi/2}, ImageSize -> 300];
pic2 = Show[
  ContourPlot[Re[f[x+I*y]],{x,0,3},{y,0,Pi/2},
    ContourShading -> False],
  ContourPlot[Im[f[x+I*y]],{x,0,3},{y,0,Pi/2},
    ContourShading -> False],
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400
];
Row[{pic1,pic2}]
```

There should be many more examples at the Wolfram Demonstrations site.

[image]

Comment: Such a domain-codomain representation can be made more meaningful by using various dynamic treatments, e.g., allowing the user to move a Locator in the domain and seeing its image in the codomain; or moving (for such a polar plot) the radial segment or the circular arc and seeing the corresponding image in the codomain. And David Park's *Presentations* application makes doing this easier, since among other things it can directly process geometric objects described in terms of complex numbers without having to separate things into real and complex parts.

Comment: @murray Like this one: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MappingRectanglesByTheElementaryTranscendentalFunctions/?

Comment: no, not quite like your demonstration (except that, like all such, it makes certain curves to curves). The ones by David Park and I (1) use polar as well as rectangular coordinates; either map a Locator point to its image or else vary a parameter to move a curve in domain and its image in codomain; use *Presentations* for simplicity in programming and true-to-the-spirit direct use of complex numbers and complex-valued curves.

Answer (score 13):

Just use `ParametricPlot` and split up the real and imaginary parts as shown below:

```
eqn = (25 Pi f I)/(1 + 10 Pi f I)
ParametricPlot[{Re[eqn], Im[eqn]}, {f, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Note that you can use `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`:=`) here.

Comment: Thanks. When should one use the `SetDelayed` versus `Set` preferably. Because I know that I usually use and see others use it when defining independent variables to your function such as Artes has done. This looks a bit different from what I got using a different program. I wonder whats that about?

Comment: Try this: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html

Comment: Thanks, for that link. That was helpful to distinguish the two. `:)`.

Answer (score 10):

There are several new functions in M12 that can be used to plot complex values. For functions of a real variable there are [`ReImPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReImPlot) and [`AbsArgPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsArgPlot). For your function they give:

```
ReImPlot[eqn, {f, -.25, .25}]
```

[image]

```
AbsArgPlot[eqn, {f, -.25, .25}, PlotRange->{{-.25,.25},{0, 2.5}}]
```

[image]

For visualizations over a complex domain, you can use [`ComplexPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot) or [`ComplexPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot3D). Using celtschk's example of `Gamma[z]`:

```
ComplexPlot3D[Gamma[z], {z, -3.5 - 3.5 I, 3.5 + 5.5 I}, PlotRange->{0,4}]
```

[image]