# How can I plot the complex graph of $x^x$ in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, complex

For example, this [Wolfram Alpha query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+raised+to+x&incTime=true) shows this graph:

[image]

But it does not show the code for plotting it in *Mathematica*.
`Plot[x^x, {x, -1, 1}]` only plots the real values. How can I do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Try this:`Plot[{Re[x^x], Im[x^x]}, {x, -1, 2}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: ...then there's also [this](http://peda.com/grafeq/gallery/rogue/xx_exponential.html)... (one of the vagaries of having to choose a "principal branch" for the logarithm)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/how-to-plot-imaginary-part-of-a-function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Plot[{Re[x^x], Im[x^x]}, {x, -1, 2}]
```

Answer (score 34):

Here's a view that shows how the graph starts to spiral for negative $x$ values, if we take the complex values into account.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, Re[Exp[x*Log[x]]], Im[Exp[x*Log[x]]]}, 
  {x, -4, 2}, PlotRange -> All, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0},
  BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 12}]
```

[image]

In fact, if we write $x^x = e^{x\log(x)}$, this naturally generallizes to $x^x = e^{x\log(x) + 2i\pi k}$; each $2i\pi k$ represents another branch of the complex logarithm. In this context, we see that this graph just forms one spiral of a family of spirals.

```
x2x[0.0, _] = x2x[0, _] = 1;
x2x[x_, k_] := Exp[x (Log[x] + 2 I Pi k)];
Table[points3D[k] = Table[
  z =  x2x[x, k];
  {x, Re[z], Im[z]},
  {x, -4, 2, 0.005}],
{k, -7, 7}];
Graphics3D[Table[{If[k == 0, Thick, Opacity[0.5]], 
  Line[points3D[k]]}, {k, -4, 4}],    
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-4, 2}, {-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, 
  BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 12}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}]
```

[image]

In elementary classes, you might see the claim that $(p/q)^{p/q}$ is defined for $p$ negative and $q$ odd and positive.  Thus, including these points, the graph might look something like so:

```
points = Union[Cases[Table[Chop[points3D[k], 1/10], {k, -7, 7}], 
  {_?Negative, _, 0}, {2}]];
Plot[x^x, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
  Epilog -> Point[Most /@ points], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 4}}]
```

[image]

From the complex perspective, the dots arise as spots where one of the spiral threads punctures the $x$-$z$ plane.

Comment: I chose yulinlinyu's as the answer because it answered my question directly and succinctly - but Mark Mcclure's answer goes above and beyond - and is the real jewel in this thread!

Answer (score 18):

As yulinyu has pointed out, something like the following will give you the desired plot.

```
Plot[Through[{Re, Im}[x^x]], {x, -2, 2}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

You might also be interested in [this excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7359/5) by Simon Woods to create a graph of the plot over the complex domain. Using his function and evaluating the following gives you a pretty picture

```
domainPlot[#^# &]
```

[image]

Comment: For a second I thought I smoked .... but no

Comment: Are you training your hypno-powers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new in M12 functions [`ReImPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReImPlot) and [`ComplexPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot) for complex visualizations of a function. Using [`ReImPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReImPlot):

```
ReImPlot[z^z, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

and [`ComplexPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot):

```
ComplexPlot[z^z, {z, - 3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
ComplexPlot3D[z^z, {z, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}]
```

[image]

does the job in version 12.0.