# Plot cubic root which includes the negative graph

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding real roots of negative numbers (for example, $\sqrt\[3\]{-8}$)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8)

Yes, I know there are other Threads which have similar questions and yes I read them but I am just not able to solve the problem. Please help me I am totally at the limit with this :(

How do I plot a cubic root in Mathematica, where also the negative graph is shown?
[image: cubic root in plot without negative graph]

NOTE: Threads I have found and not understood

[How to plot imaginary part of a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/how-to-plot-imaginary-part-of-a-function)

[Finding real roots of negative numbers (for example, $\sqrt[3]{-8}$)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8/3888#3888)

[Plotting Complex Quantity Functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions/3460#3460)

Comment: The second question you linked to would definitely be a duplicate. Why not explain what you did not understand about any of those threads? Something you specifically had trouble with, perhaps?

Comment: Using one of the linked questions, one might be inspired to try `Plot[Root[#^3 - x &, 1], {x, -2, 2}]`, which works.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution to this type of problem is usually to use a function like `Solve` or `NSolve` to generate solutions to an equation, which can then be plotted.

In this case, I would do the following:

```
Plot[p /. NSolve[p^3 == x, p, Reals], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image: a plot of the cube root]

All I am doing is plotting `p` such that `p` is a solution to `p^3 == x`.  `NSolve` allows me to force the result to be a real number.

This is a (very) minor variation on the techniques mentioned in solutions that you link in your question.

I recommend that you read [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeRoot.html) for more information on why *Mathematica* does what it does.  Essentially, real numbers have unique cube roots, but (non-zero) complex numbers have 3 distinct roots.  *Mathematica* assumes that all symbols are complex, so it has a choice about which of the 3 roots it could return.  For reasons explained in the link, *Mathematica* chooses the complex root with a positive imaginary part.

---

**Addendum by J. M.**

In version 9, one now has the new functions `CubeRoot[]`, which returns real-valued cube roots of real numbers (and does not evaluate for complex arguments), and the more general `Surd[]`. See the documentation for details.