# Real and Imaginary plots of the answer to $\int \sec x\, dx$

Tags: plotting, complex

I used free-from input to do this:

= integrate sec x with respect to x

I got a huge amount of information, but I'd like to focus on this plot that was given:

[image]

Can my colleagues show how to do this plot?

It's also interesting that Mathematica gives this answer:

In[91]:= Integrate[Sec[x], x]

Out[91]= -Log[Cos[x/2] - Sin[x/2]] + Log[Cos[x/2] + Sin[x/2]]

But if we click on Step-by-step-solutions, Wolfram Alpha gives this answer:

[image]

Which is similar to the hand-calculated solution

$$\ln|\sec x+\tan x|+C$$

found by students in Calculus II.

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/how-to-plot-imaginary-part-of-a-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the CAS system. $\int \sec(t) \, dt$ gives

```
Mathematica:     ln(cos(t/2)+sin(t/2))-ln(cos(t/2)-sin(t/2))
Wolfram/ALpha:   ln(tan(t)+sec(t))+ constant
Rubi:            arctanh(sin(t))
Fricas:          1/2 ( ln(1+sin(t)) - ln(1-sin(t)) )
Maple            ln(sec(t)+tan(t))
Derive 6.10      LN(TAN((2*t + pi)/4))
Maxima           log((1+sin(x))/cos(x))
```

As for your plot, you can do

```
expr = Log[Sec[x] + Tan[x]];
Plot[{Re@expr, Im@expr}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"real part", "imaginary part"}, 
    PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[expr]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

reference: [sci.math.symbolic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math.symbolic/7KQcXCCzIrw)

Comment: Really nice answer. I learned a lot from your help. Thanks.