# Empty plot when calling the SphericalHarmonicY function in Plot or SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I'm getting an empty plot for the following code:

```
SphericalPlot3D[
 2*Pi*Sin[theta]*SphericalHarmonicY[100, 50, theta, phi], {theta, 0, 2*Pi}, {phi, 0 , Pi}]
```

Also, if I set `phi` to a specific value and plot in 1D, an empty plot is printed.

Any thoughts? 
Thanks.

Comment: `Sin (theta)` should be `Sin[theta]`, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Because it is complex function. So you have to decide what to plot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting Complex Quantity Functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions)

Answer (score 1):

```
Grid[{{Abs, Re, Im}, 
  SphericalPlot3D[2 π Sin[θ] #@ 
       SphericalHarmonicY[10, 5, θ, φ], {θ, 0, 2 π}, {φ, 0, 2 π},
     PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
     PlotPoints -> 40,PlotRange -> All,
     Mesh -> {5, 10},MeshStyle -> {Opacity[0.1], Darker@Purple},
     Boxed -> False, Axes -> False] & /@ {Abs, Re, Im}},
 Frame -> All]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

`SphericalHarmonicY[100, 50, θ, φ]` takes so long time.

```
SphericalPlot3D[2 π Sin[θ] Abs@ 
   SphericalHarmonicY[100, 50, θ, φ], {θ, 0, 2 π}, {φ, 0, 2 π},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3],PlotPoints -> 150,
 PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {50, 10},
 MeshStyle -> {Opacity[0.1], Darker@Purple},
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

> [image: Blockquote]