# How can I plot the complex formula as follow?

Tags: plotting

I try for this ...
[image: I try for this]

I want to see the result like this

[image: Plots from web]

```
Plot[(-1.047-1.50133 I)*E^((-0.34381+1.35844 I) t) *(1+ Erf[(0.72714+0.9341 
I)* Sqrt(t))+((-1.047+1.50133 I)*E^((-0.34381-1.35844 I) t)*
1+Erf[(0.72714-0.9341 I)*Sqrt(t))]
```

Comment: Is it supposed that people willing to help will rewrite the formula from an image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting Complex Quantity Functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: As noted by @m0nhawk, please enter your code in the question with Mathematica format.

Comment: @m0nhawk  yes,because the image is from the http://www.wolframalpha.com/  ,but I want to use Mathematica to show it.
I also try the method of "Plotting Complex Quantity Functions " still can't plot it.

Comment: @Erergo You should copy and paste textual code into this question, not an image of it.  But this is probably also a duplicate.

Comment: @Erergo it's not good for someone to retype that kind of equation. Copy a text. Also, from what I've see, you have a miniscule `i`, and in *Mathematica* imaginary unit is a capital `I`.

Comment: Two other problems are evident from the image.  First `e` should be `E`.  Second, `Plot` does not handle complex numbers.

Comment: sorry ,I use this web first time,let me learn how to paste the code.

Comment: Thank you.  I cleaned up the format a bit for you.  I am not sure why you got the more complicated output from *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you too much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In seems that your function has an imaginary part of zero for all inputs in range:

```
expr[t_] := (-1.047 - 1.50133 I)*
   E^((-0.34381 + 1.35844 I) t)*(1 + Erf[(0.72714 + 0.9341 I) *Sqrt[t]]) + (-1.047 + 
     1.50133 I)*E^(( -0.34381 - 1.35844 I) t)*(1 + Erf[(0.72714 - 0.9341  I)*Sqrt[t]])

Table[Im[expr[t]], {t, 0, 15, 0.1}] // Union
```

> ```
> {0.}
> ```