# A question about ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I already tried to ask this question, but it was unclear what I meant, so I will try to ask it again and explain it more carrefully.

For example I will use a toy problem. Suppose we have equation:

```
eq=k*x^2 + 2*x + 1
```

I want to use ContourPlot, to plot the curves where `eq=0` for some values of `x` and`k`. If `x` and `k` are both real, this is easy to do:

```
ContourPlot[eq == 0, {k, 0, 2}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

But I want to treat `x` as complex variable, and `k` as real variable. For any real `k` we have 2 complex roots of the equation `eq==0`. I am not interested in `Im[x]`, I only interested in `Re[x]`. So want I want is something like this:

```
ContourPlot[eq == 0, {k, 0, 2}, {Re[x], -3, 3}]
```

So, for each `k`, it should solve the equation `eq==0`, and plot `Re[x]` against `k`, omitting `Im[x]`. I want 2D plot, I don't want 3D plot. (My original problem is linear stability analythis, where `x` is groth rate, `k` is wave number).

Say it another way: basically, we have here 3 parameters (complex `x` + real `k`). I want to plot `Re[x]` against `k`, ignoring `Im[x]`, so it is like a projection of 3D curve to 2D surface.

Note: [Plotting Complex Quantity Functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions) doesn't solve my problem.

Note:

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[k (reX + imX I)^2 + 2 (reX + imX I) + 1 == 0, {k, 0, 2}, {reX, -3, 3}], {imX, -3, 3}]
```

Doesn't solve it as well: I don't want to manipulate `Im[x]`, I want to omit it, whatever it is.

Comment: march, I add another explanation: this is like a projection of 3D curve  (with parameters `Re[x]`, `Im[x]`, k) to 2D space (with only 2 parameters: `Re[x]` and `k`)

Comment: march, there is no freedom: for each `k`, you can solve the equation and find 2 complex roots. So I want to plot real part of this roots against `k`, omitting imaginary part of the roots. Where did you find freedom??

Comment: How complicated is your general equation? Is it algebraically separable into real and imaginary parts if you write `x = Re[x] + I Im[x]`? Or will have you have imaginary numbers inside special functions like, say, `Erf`?

Comment: march, it is of the third order, but numbers are crazy sometimes. I know, that I can separate it and solve for both real and imaginary part, then plot what I want. But it is much more safe to do `ContourPlot`, rather then solving it exactly

Comment: Understood. @george2079's `ContourPlot` method is very clever. I'm working on another method that requires the separability, but it's hard to get it to work, so I may not end up posting an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a crude way to generate the plot:

```
Graphics[Point[
     Flatten[Table[ {k, #} & /@ 
        Re[x /. Solve[ k x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0  , x]], {k, -3, 3, .01}], 
            1]], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

clipping the plot range..and with `Axes->True`

[image]

Edit: a trick to coax `ContourPlot` to do the job:

```
f[k_, x_] := (Re[y] /. 
   Solve[ k (x + y)^2 + 2 (x + y) + 1 == 0  , y] )[[1]]
g[k_, x_] := (Re[y] /. 
   Solve[ k (x + y)^2 + 2 (x + y) + 1 == 0  , y] )[[2]]
ContourPlot[{ f[k, x] == 0, g[k, x] == 0}, {k, -3, 3}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is that possible to everything in log-log scale?

Comment: work with `ListLogLogPlot` (wont work for the toy example however because there are no results for `k,x` both positive )

Comment: Thanks again. That solves my problem.

Comment: No, it's not. This is a root `x=(-2+sqrt(4-k))/(2k)`. Unless `k` is very small, negative k results in a small `x`. Nice trick, btw, to assume `x=a+b`, where `a` is real,  `b` is complex, and then set `Re[b]=0`, which automatically results in arbitrary pure imaginary b.

Comment: x is not precisely zero there. I think, you are confusing x-axis with k-axis (horizontal axis is k axis, vertical is x-axis). If you are talking about vertical line k=0,than yes, there is a problem, but it arises from the fact, that the equation I provided is singular when k=0: it becomes first order. If you will try to use formula `x=(-2+-sqrt(4-k))/(2k)` for `k=0`, you will get `0/0`

Comment: No, I wasn't confusing them, I was just wrong. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: No problem. Thank you too for the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `ParametricPlot`:

```
{k, Re[x]} /.
        Solve[k x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x] //
    ParametricPlot[#, {k, -5, 5}] &
```

[image: k vs Re[x]]

Comment: @MikhailGenkin You're welcome :)