# Residue simplifies to ComplexInfinity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have `Residue` calculation that depends on a parameter `r`, for which I assume

```
$Assumptions = {r > 0};
```

I'm interested in the residue of the function

$\frac{1}{\left(z^{4/3}+\left(-1\right)^{1/3}r^{4/3}\right)\left(z^{2}-r^{2}\right)}$

at $z=-r$.

The calculation is:

```
Residue[1/((z^(4/3) + Power[-1, (3)^-1] r^(4/3))   (z^2 - 
     r^2)), {z, -r}] // Simplify
```

> ComplexInfinity

However, If I first assign a value to `r` and then take the `Residue`

```
Residue[1/((z^(4/3) + Power[-1, (3)^-1] r^(4/3))   (z^2 - r^2)) /. 
  r -> 1, {z, -1}]
```

> 1/4 (-1)^(2/3)

The output is finite.

What am I missing? Thanks.

**Edit 5.4.18**

From the comment section of a different [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170410/evaluating-residue-at-pole-with-different-forms/170414?noredirect=1#comment447968_170414) of mine I learned that `Residue` in Mathematica versions prior to 11.1 may be buggy. Switching to 11.2, now I get:

```
$Assumptions = {r > 0};
Residue[1/((z^(4/3) + Power[-1, (3)^-1] r^(4/3)) (z^2 - r^2)), {z, -r}]
Residue[1/((z^(4/3) + Power[-1, (3)^-1] r^(4/3)) (z^2 - r^2)) /. 
  r -> 1, {z, -1}]
```

> Residue[1/(((-1)^(1/3) r^(4/3) + z^(4/3)) (-r^2 + z^2)), {z, -r}]
>
> Residue[1/(((-1)^(1/3) + z^(4/3)) (-1 + z^2)), {z, -1}]

Meaning, `Residue` fails and does not change the input in both cases.

Also, I decided to plot the complex function for $r=1$ using the function in [celtschk's answer in a diffrent post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions), and got:

[image: plot of the complex function]

We can see that in $z=-r=-1$ there's a discontinuity, which *may be* consistent with a problematic Laurent series and the inexistence of the residue.

Still, if I remove the assumption that $r>0$, Residue returns the previously problematic output:

```
$Assumptions = {};
Residue[1/((z^(4/3) + Power[-1, (3)^-1] r^(4/3)) (z^2 - 
       r^2)), {z, -r}] // Simplify
```

> -(1/(-2 (-r)^(7/3) + 2 (-1)^(1/3) r^(7/3)))

Comment: There is no Laurent series in a neighborhood of `z=-r` so it's hard to say what `Residue` might come up with in that situation.

Comment: the cube root of $-1$ is just $-1$. Take a look at the documentation of `CubeRoot` of the Wolfram language. It gives to me zero with this code ``Refine[Residue[1/((z^(4/3) - r^(4/3)) (z^2 - r^2)), {z, -r}], r > 0]``. Well, using `Power` you probably will get the principal value of the cube roots of unity.

Comment: with this code ``Refine[Residue[
  1/((z^(4/3) + (-1)^(1/3) r^(4/3)) (z^2 - r^2)), {z, -r}], r > 0]`` it gives this result ``-(1/(2 (-(-r)^(1/3) + (-1)^(1/3) r^(1/3)) r^2))``

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, how do you know there is no Laurent series? If there isn't, then Residue should fail no?

Comment: @Masacroso, cube root of 1 is not 1, it's e^(i*pi/3), that's what is meant by the formula I showed, copied from the Mathematica notebook. As in your second comment, the result simplifies to ComplexInfinity. Also, using Refine with r>0 is the same as first declaring r>0 in $Assumptions.

Comment: Actually looking again I'm not sure. The fractional power gives rise to a series that, in Mathematica, uses `Piecewise` to handle `Im[z] >= 0` vs. `Im[z] < 0`. But I am not sure the two are actually different in a way that would preclude the existence of a residue.

Comment: @TalArsenyMiller WolframMathematica distinguishes `Cuberoot` from `Power`. Read the documentation of each command. That is `Cuberoot[1]==1` but `Power[1,1/3]==E^(I Pi/3)`