# Evaluating Residue at pole with different forms

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to evaluate residues at the poles of the function 
$\frac{1}{z^{3/2}+r^{3/2}}$

```
fun = 1/ (z^(3/2) + r^(3/2));
```

where `z` is the variable, and `r` is a real and positive parameter.

Analytically, there are 2 poles at $z = e^{\pm 2/3 \pi i} r$.

**Side Problem:**

When I solve for the roots of the denominator, I only get one of the solutions above:

```
Solve[Denominator[fun] == 0, z]
```

> {{z -> (-r^(3/2))^(2/3)}}

This can be checked to be indeed the solution above with the plus sign:

```
(-r^(3/2))^(2/3)/(E^(2/3 π I) r) // Simplify
```

> 1

Any idea why `Solve` did not find both solutions? Can I "help" it in some way to find both?

**Main Problem:**

Evaluating the residue using `Residue` only accepts the form of the solution given by `Solve`:

```
Residue[fun, {z, (-r^(3/2))^(2/3)}]
Residue[fun, {z, E^(2/3 π I) r}]
```

> -((2 (-r^(3/2))^(2/3))/(3 r^(3/2)))
>
> 0

How do I "convince" Mathematica to accept my form of the pole? Or am I wrong in some way? Thanks.

Comment: `Assuming[r > 0, Solve[Denominator[fun] == 0]]` yields both solutions.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform , actually, even without the "Assuming", `Solve[Denominator[fun] == 0]` yields both, but `Solve[Denominator[fun] == 0, z]` doesnt. This is strange, but I do want to specify which variable I'm solving for. In a different case, it could have solved for `r` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not documented, [`Residue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Residue) does take the [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions) option:

```
Options[Residue]
```

> {Assumptions :> $Assumptions}

If you use [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions), then [`Residue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Residue) is able to give the desired result:

```
Residue[fun, {z, E^(2/3 π I) r}, Assumptions->r>0]
```

> -((2 E^((2 I π)/3))/(3 Sqrt[r]))

Comment: The lines `fun = 1/(z^(3/2) + r^(3/2)); Residue[fun, {z, E^(2/3 π I) r}, Assumptions->r>0]` give 0 nonetheless for me. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: @TalArsenyMiller Looks like you might be using M10 or earlier? If you use M11 it should work.

Comment: I have M11. I asked a friend that also has M11 to run that line, also got 0.
I also noticed that if I first give a numeric value to `r`, for example `r=1/2`, I get a non-zero result. On the other hand `r=0.5` gives zero again.

Comment: @TalArsenyMiller Which version of M11? It works for 11.1, 11.2, and 11.3 for me (on OSX but that shouldn't make a difference). Also, I'm not surprised that Residue with an inexact number produces 0.

Comment: The problem I had was indeed on 11.0, switched to 11.2 and problem disappeared. Thanks alot.
What do you think about my "side problem", and the comment above given by AccidentalFourierTransform?

Comment: I found in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve) the form `Solve[eq, z, Method -> Reduce]` which does the job