# Why Does Mathematica Have Trouble Plotting This?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, complex

I'm trying to [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) something relatively simple:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Ωm*E^(I*(J - Ωm)*t), {t, 0, 100}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], {J, 1, 100}, {Ωm, 10, 100}]
```

But *Mathematica* just returns a blank plot of the first quadrant. I figure that it might be because I'm using a complex exponential (although it's never been a problem before), but I just wanted to make sure

Comment: use `Re[\[CapitalOmega]m*E^(I*(J - \[CapitalOmega]m)*t)]` or `Im[\[CapitalOmega]m*E^(I*(J - \[CapitalOmega]m)*t)]` as the first argument in `Plot`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are trying to plot a complex number. You can separate [`Re`al](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html) and [`Im`aginary](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Im.html) parts with [`ReIm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate@ReIm[
    Ωm*E^(I*(J - Ωm)*t)
    ]
  , {t, 0, 100}
  , ImageSize -> Large
  , PlotRange -> {-102, 102}
  , PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]
  , PlotPoints -> 100
  , MaxRecursion -> 10
  , PlotLegends -> {Re, Im}
 ]
 , {{J, 49}, 1, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , {{Ωm, 50}, 10, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: @rhermans Many thanks